# Not able to find ("section") in ie browser

Tags: jquery, xml

In ie browser find("Section") not working
i am having this xml content

```
    var xmlContent = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?/><Section type="two_column" name="Section Name" id="attr_id_lines_9810"><Column align="Left"><Label>One</Label><Value>test</Value></Column><Column align="Right"><Label>Two</Label><Value>222</Value></Column></Section>';
$(xmlContent).find("Section").each(function(){console.log($(this).attr('type");});
```

In ie browser this code not working. but other browser it display correct result.
if any one know solution please update.

Comment: It's failing because you're treating xml like html rather than xml.

Comment: @KevinB jQuery is capable of parsing xml as well :)

Comment: @Archer Yes, it is. But what he's doing above is he's parsing xml as HTML, and since IE<9 doesn't consider `section` as a valid html element, it can't select it without a shim. If he instead used $.parseXML() and then wrapped THAT in $(), he could navigate it normally. (though his current navigation chain is still wrong)

Comment: Ah okay - I wasn't aware of the earlier limitations (and I avoid IE like the plague!)  Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The XML Declaration is not a "self-closing" or paired tag. Remove the slash.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?/>
```

should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
```

Use `filter()`, not `.find()` as "Section" is not a child element.
You also have a mismatched quote and you are missing a closing parentheses (either of which will drive IE nuts).

```
$(xmlContent).find("Section").each(function(){console.log($(this).attr('type");});
```

should be:

```
$(xmlContent).filter("Section").each(function(){console.log($(this).attr('type'));});
```

Put together, that's:

```
var xmlContent = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><Section type="two_column" name="Section Name" id="cust_attr_estimate_lines_9810"><Column align="Left"><Label>One</Label><Value>test</Value></Column><Column align="Right"><Label>Two</Label><Value>222</Value></Column></Section>';
$(xmlContent).filter("Section").each(function () {
    console.log($(this).attr('type'));
});
```

and I can run that in the Developer Tools console in IE8 (and FF and Chrome), getting the expected result (`two_column`) without any problems.